# PHY device not responding to MDIO

Tags: c, ethernet, phy

> Update: I have read more about this and what I can conclude is that the phy IC is not initialized correctly. Still no able to figure out how to initialize phy device. Please go through the code and strap configurations and let me know where the error is.

I am using the K60DN512 device with 8720A PHY IC. I have written a simple program to communicate with the PHY IC. I have checked it on logic analyser and I am not getting any response from the PHY device. What can be possible causes?

Configuration of PHY device straps.

PHYAD[0]: Pulled low.

MODE[2:0] : 011 100Base-TX Full Duplex. Auto-negotiation disabled. CRS is active during Receive.

MDIO : Pulled high.

MDC: 1 Mhz.

I am using the processor expert generated code. So in that case there shouldn't be any error. What can be the possible reason for communication failure? The value is either 0 or 0xFFFF.

```
main(){
    MAChandler = mac_Init(NULL);
    Bit1_Init(NULL);

    uint16_t id = 0;
    uint16_t value = 0;
    uint16_t timeout = 0;
    uint16_t count = 0;
    uint8_t sfr = 0;

    const uint8_t netifLINK_DELAY = 3;
    do {
        mii_read(id, PHY_PHYIDR1, &value);
        count++;
    } while (value == 0xffff);

    do {
        value = 0xffff;
        mii_read(id, sfr, &value);
        if (value != 0xffff)
            sfr++;
        count++;
    } while (sfr <= 0x1F);

    uint16 config;
    do {
        config = 0x2200;
        mii_write(id, PHY_BMCR, config);
        uint16_t i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 0xFF; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 0xFFFF; j++)
                ;
        mii_read(id, PHY_BMCR, &value);
        count++;
    } while (value != config);
}

int mii_write(int phy_addr, int reg_addr, uint16_t data) {
    int timeout;

    /* Clear the MII interrupt bit */ENET_EIR /*(ch)*/= ENET_EIR_MII_MASK;
    /* Initiatate the MII Management write */ENET_MMFR /*(ch)*/=
            0 | ENET_MMFR_ST(0x01) | ENET_MMFR_OP(0x01) | ENET_MMFR_PA(phy_addr)
                    | ENET_MMFR_RA(reg_addr) | ENET_MMFR_TA(0x02)
                    | ENET_MMFR_DATA(data);

    /* Poll for the MII interrupt (interrupt should be masked) */
    for (timeout = 0; timeout < MII_TIMEOUT; timeout++) {
        if (ENET_EIR /*(ch)*/& ENET_EIR_MII_MASK)
            break;
    }

    if (timeout == MII_TIMEOUT)
        return 1;
    /* Clear the MII interrupt bit */ENET_EIR /*(ch)*/= ENET_EIR_MII_MASK;
    return 0;
}

/********************************************************************/
/*!
 * \brief   Read a value from a PHY's MII register.
 * \param   phy_addr    Address of the PHY
 * \param   reg_addr    Address of the register in the PHY
 * \param   data        Pointer to location were read data will be stored
 * \return  0 if write is successful; 1 if write times out
 *
 * mii_read() polls for the FEC's MII interrupt event (which should
 * be masked from the interrupt handler) and clears it. If after a
 * suitable amount of time the event isn't triggered, a non-zero value 
 * is returned.
 */

int mii_read(int phy_addr, int reg_addr, uint16_t *data) {
    int timeout;
    /* Clear the MII interrupt bit */ENET_EIR /*(ch)*/= ENET_EIR_MII_MASK;
    Bit1_SetVal(NULL); // Indication that the MDIO transfer is about to begin.
    /* Initiatate the MII Management read */ENET_MMFR /*(ch)*/= 0
            | ENET_MMFR_ST(0x01) | ENET_MMFR_OP(0x2) | ENET_MMFR_PA(phy_addr)
            | ENET_MMFR_RA(reg_addr) | ENET_MMFR_TA(0x02);

    /* Poll for the MII interrupt (interrupt should be masked) */
    for (timeout = 0; timeout < MII_TIMEOUT; timeout++) {
        if (ENET_EIR /*(ch)*/& ENET_EIR_MII_MASK){
            Bit1_ClrVal(NULL); // Indication that the MDIO transfer is complete.
            break;
        }
    }
    if (timeout == MII_TIMEOUT)
        return 1;

    /* Clear the MII interrupt bit */ENET_EIR /*(ch)*/= ENET_EIR_MII_MASK;
    uint16_t test = ENET_MMFR /*(ch)*/& 0x0000FFFF;
    *data = ENET_MMFR /*(ch)*/& 0x0000FFFF;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, post better formatted code next time. Cheers and Welcome to SE.EE!

Comment: I think the code is pretty well formatted, I am myself very critical about it. Still if there are any specific suggestions, let me know

Comment: For some reason the code you posted had a blank line between every code line. If it looks better now it's because I edited it. Click the edit link above my name and avatar above to see the edit history and check how your original post was being rendered.

Comment: No problem. I guess it was an end-of-line converting problem. After I removed the extra lines, the code looked good indeed. It shows that you care. Cheers! -(-1)+1=+2.

Comment: A few silly questions : Did you create the board ? Is the PHY powered and with a running clock ? Did you check the RESET pin ? Does the PHY auto-connects after a power-up ? (most PHY start autonegotiation as soon as they are powered, without needing MDIO configuration)

Comment: @TEMLIB Yes we have designed the board.

Comment: 1. Yes we have designed the board, we did get the schematic reviewed from Freescale and two more sources. I think there is no issue with hardware design. I have tested 3 boards, response is same. So at least for hardware part I feel it is 90% correct.
2. The reset Pin is connected to GPIO pin of the microcontroller, with a DNP resister, so technically it is floating open. Haven't checked the status. Will do that. 
3.  I don't think the PHY device is doing auto-negotiation. The LEDs don't glow if we connect it to our router (DHCP is enabled).

Comment: I have checked the reset pin, it is pulled up. We have now placed a 100 ohms resister between the nRST pin and GPIO. We have done a hardware reset as given in datasheet, still no response.

Comment: There is no mentioning in the [LAN8720A datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/8720a.pdf) about PHYAD[4:1] are zeros. (While you're using `id = 0` to access the PHY by `mii_read(id,...)` and `mii_write(id,...)` routines.) It is strange in twice because as per IEEE Std 802.3, Clause 22 the 00000 (five zeros) address is like "broadcast" and it may show unpredictable behavior on read (IC dependent).

Comment: Maybe it's less off-topic, but looking at the quality of the code you designed, your assumption about the hardware (you designed too) is ok sounds slightly unconvincingly. Sorry please if it is not.